# Compounding performance problems in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Let me start off by saying I understand performance is hard, and even harder through a forum, but I hope someone can point me towards the next step of figuring out this problem we're having in production on a Ruby on Rails environment.  I've been seeing this for a while, but now with our usage down due to Covid, it's become more clear that it's not a user-load issue, but something in the infrastructure.

[image: NewRelic Transaction Time]

The day starts off fine, but midday, things slow more and more... until a passenger restart clears everything up for 24/48/96 hours.

Checking the obvious items:

- Server memory usage is in check. Memory use increases during this time from 20%-30%.  So some increase, but definitely not swapping (I've seen that happen before)
- CPU usage is similar.  It increases from 1% at 6am to 18% at worst case, but still well within the capabilities of the server.
- Passenger usage. Looking at passenger-status, there's never a backlog of requests.  Because of covid, our user-base is down, and even at its slowest, I'm seeing 2-3 passenger processes serving content (out of ~40 max), and no long-running requests.
- Delayed job workers (3) are running, but no jobs at the time.  They don't seem to be using a significant amount of cpu or mem
- Watching the apache/rails logs, nothing looks awry.  No DoSes, no unexpected load.
- Looking at long-running transactions in NewRelic, there are some that are taking 20-30-50 sec, but after the passenger restart, they are back to 1-3 sec like usual.  All the time is in Ruby.

So this is where I'm stuck.  I can see where the problem is (185 sec):
[image: Example of one long-running transaction segment]

but if I restart passenger and re-run, that same code will take less than a second. And that's just the example that I see from today's traces.  Yesterday, it looked like it was a different controller having problems.

Any recommendations on my next steps to troubleshoot?  I don't know if I should instrument a specific controller, because it's not just one method that's causing the problem (afaik). I think I'm seeing the symptoms, not the cause - and no idea how to see what's really going on.

Thanks in advance
-Mike

Rails 4.2.11.1
Ruby 2.4.9
Passenger 6.0.5 on Apache 2.4.43

Comment: A service such as [Scout APM](https://scoutapm.com/) can give you detailed time-sliced performance information with stack traces and database analysis.

Comment: Most likely scenario is either you have some queries that are taking too long, check your table cache hit rate/index cache hit rate and see what they're at.

Comment: Thanks Schwern, we invested in NewRelic, and it's been great - but I'm admittedly still learning how to dive into some of the details.  Ricks - will take a look, I've wondered if the db is blocking somehow... will do more research and post back.